# textblock.setvalue in c# wpf how does it work

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, setvalue

Can anyone give me information on how the setvalue on a textblock works?
Can't find good information about it.
definitions used in this code:

```
//sourcenode definition
public DependencyProperty SourceNode = 

Constants.HierarchyNodeProperty;
//HierarchyNodeProperty  definition
public static DependencyProperty HierarchyNodeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SourceNode", typeof(HierarchyNode), typeof(Constants));
//textblock setvalue
this.TextBlock.SetValue(SourceNode, this);
```

Any information that makes sense might help. Like links etc.

Comment: explore the source - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/BindingBase.cs,8a32b385798827dc

Answer (score 0):

[SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is a function available to DependencyObjects which sets the value of a DependencyProperty to the provided value.

What your code seems to do is set the SourceNode DP of a property (named TextBlock and of unknown type) to this.

TextBlock is a poor name for a property and SourceNode is a poor name for a DP.